# Android change actionbar buttons

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar

I have an application that can make voice recording but I'm stuck with implementing the UI. There is a button in my action bar and when is clicked I want to collapse all I have in the action bar and show the buttons that will be for recording and playing the recorded.

To get the idea:
This is my actionbar

---

```
     b1 b2 b3 b4
```

---

When b3 is clicked:

---

```
    play  record
```

---

Can you give me an advise how to do that. I'm also interested in other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

When a button is pressed, then call `Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu()`

This will cause `onCreateContextMenu()` to be called again. Inside that method have some sort of flag that will allow you to determine which menu to inflate.

edit for use of support action bar          **super.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int x = item.getItemId();
    switch (x) {
    case R.id.action_track:
        super.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: it gives me this error: Multiple markers at this line
 - Activity cannot be resolved
 - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method invalidateOptionsMenu() from the type 
  Activity

Also I don't have onCreateContextMenu()
I have public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)